# Why use UPPER or LOWER for SQL Server procedure parameters?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2012. I've noticed the `WHERE` clauses for text are not case sensitive. So why do some people use the following format in a procedure?

```
 WHERE UPPER(fieldName) = UPPER(@fieldName)
```

Does this have something to do with calling the procedure from another program, using another programming language? Or is this exclusive to transact SQL?

I can write in my clause

```
WHERE fieldname = 'UNITED STATES'
```

and it will return all records with either United States, united states, uNiteD STateS, etc.

Comment: It can be case sensitive... depends on the collation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Oh I see. Cool thanks for the answer and the link.

Comment: No Problem. You'll likely run into collation "differences" when you are joining tables from different servers, or dealing with DB's in other languages. Definitely worth reading up on. Cheers

Comment: @scsimon you should just post that in the answer so that it can be accepted and no longer show up in the unanswered list. +1

Comment: Fair enough @SqlZim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be case sensitive... depends on the collation.

[MSDN Documentation on Collation (one of many)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250(v=sql.105).aspx)

You'll likely run into collation "differences" when you are joining tables from different servers, or dealing with DB's in other languages. Definitely worth reading up on